# What does status finished mean in Google Chrome developer tools network tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Somehow my javascript files are not loaded (size = 0) and in status I see the text "Finished". JS fails to operate. Does anyone know what is wrong and what I should do?

Comment: maybe JS is disabled?

Comment: chrome not loading only local files, remote does, what is wrong? I guess maybe some directive in js is set, by the way I use requirejs [maybe it is related]

Comment: not it's not related, as I said in previous comment - tested

Comment: Solved, local files which I try to load without apache (web server) loads and chrome gives them status as finished. If I load under web server I receive status of 200

Comment: I have the same issue. It only happens for a few out of 1000's of customers. In our case, it is our normal GET requests to IIS for JSON that are being skipped and end up showing as "Finished" size=0. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, local files which I try to load without apache (web server) loads and chrome gives them status as finished. If I load under web server I receive status of 200

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried clearing the Cache, try force reloading the page with

> Ctrl + Shift + R (or CMD + Shift + R on Mac)

Or Chrome has a 'Disable Cache' checkbox in dev tools under the 'Network' tab.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience, the status “finished” also may indicates that the server sent the wrong status code (in my case the server responds with status code 0, but with full right body (it was backend bug)).