# Uncaught ReferenceError: initialiseSearchPage is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML file and a Javascript file.
**HTML file:**

```
<script src="../scripts/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript"> 
    initialiseSearchPage(); 
</script>
```

**search.js file:**

```
function initialiseSearchPage() {
    //code
}
```

And when I run the code I get the error in the title. Why?

Comment: Please check if path for `search.js` is correct this should work

Comment: my path is correct

Comment: are you certain? Open your developer console (press F12 in most browsers), go to the Network tab. Now refresh your page, and watch it load all the resources. Does it load search.js correctly (with a 200 OK response), or not?

Comment: How do I do it on a mac

Comment: which browser? Safari? Are you so helpless you can't open google and type "safari open developer tools"?

Comment: I'm using Internet Explorer 2

Comment: err what?? You mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_2 ? Released in 1996?? Are you living in a time warp? It does support some JavaScript features but I don't know where you'd find documentation about what exactly it can do these days, it hasn't been supported for a _long_ time. I wouldn't like to guarantee it can even support simple stuff like you're doing in your question. And yeah it definitely won't have any developer tools. I can't imagine why you're trying to develop for this platform, but I wouldn't expect much from it in terms of JavaScript.

Comment: IE 2 on Mac in 2018? Wow! What Mac version are you running and on what hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

After seeing that you use Cloudflare you need to add `data-cfasync="false"` to your search.js script like this:

```
<script src="../scripts/search.js" type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false"></script>
```

This will instruct Cloudflare not to use [Rocket Loader](https://blog.cloudflare.com/we-have-lift-off-rocket-loader-ga-is-mobile/) feature for [that script](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436--How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-)

---

**Original answer**

Check network tab in Chrome DevTools, you are probably loading search.js from wrong location. Most likely you wanted to have this:

```
<script src="/scripts/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Your scripts folder must be directly in web root folder for this setup to work.

Comment: What is the url of your page? I suspect you placed scripts folder outside of your web root folder.

Comment: Even if I put the search.js file in the same folder as my html and change src to  src="search.js" it still won't work

Comment: What does your network tab show? search.js is loaded successfully?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't mention search.js in the Network tab at all

Comment: @Maqruis1 that's impossible, if the script tag is definitely included in the HTML page you're looking at. Bear in mind you have to refresh the page after opening the Network tab (as I already mentioned in the comments above) otherwise the load of that script will already have happened and you'll miss it. Do that and try again. Check the status of search.js - if successful it will be (200 OK), if not you'll get some other code e.g. 404 or 403. P.S. I guess since you've found some developer tools we are now testing with a recent version of Chrome instead of I.E. 2?

Comment: yes I'm using Chrome. Ok Now I see the search.js in the network tab. its status says its finished

Comment: @Maqruis1 No, that's not what we're asking for, we're asking for the **HTTP status code** . It will be a 3-digit numeric value. P.S. If you don't know what a HTTP status code is, now would be a _really_ good time to go and google it.

Comment: @Maqruis1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784530/what-does-status-finished-mean-in-google-chrome-developer-tools-network-tab ...are you trying to load your page over `file://` instead of `http://`? - it's always better to use a proper webserver. As you can see, lots of your files appear to have a size of 0 bytes, which suggests they didn't get loaded.

Comment: @ADyson I have another file which works in a similar way and has no problems

Comment: @Maqruis1 are there any other errors in your Console at the same time, apart from the "undefined" one?

Comment: @Maqruis1 try clearing your cache and try again. It's also a bit odd that the script.js is shown as being initiated by another script, rather than by the HTML page. I'd expect it to be shown as initiated by the HTML, based on your code above. Are you loading some other scripts in your page too? Does that script attempt to load search.js asynchronously or something? Are you accidentally running a different version of the code than what you've shown to us?

Comment: I think you are using Rocker Loader from Cloud Flare which loads script asynchronously. So either disable Rocket Loader from your Cloud Flare account or find a way to run `initialiseSearchPage()` after Rocket Loader done loading your scripts.

Comment: Funny thing is, If I remove the javascript code from my js file and put it into the html file it loads

Comment: Yes, that's expected, please read more about what Rocker Loader does.

Comment: @Maqruis1 that's not funny at all, it's totally normal - that code is already part of your page, it's not being loaded separately, and it cannot be loaded asynchronously by another library. By the sounds of it you seem to be including this Rocket Loader thing despite having no idea what it's for or what it does - that's never a good thing to be doing, because you lose control of your application and start to have problems you don't really understand. If you don't know what something is, either don't use it, or find out what it is and decide whether you need it or not.