# The meaning of status=Finished in chrome devtool network panel? What caused?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, web, cdn

I got a HAR file from a customer, and the network shows 1 key request got a status with `Finished` and size `0`. What caused this issue? How do we solve this issue?

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Dev Tools Network Tab with one call ending with "Status" as "Finished"]

Not all users have this issue, just a few of them.

**Update**

This is a little different from another similar issue added in the comments.

1. I'm using CDN for content delivery. (That issue looks like it's using a self-owned server.)
2. In which scenario status code will show `Finished`? I don't find this in any document, so sad...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does status finished mean in Google Chrome developer tools network tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784530/what-does-status-finished-mean-in-google-chrome-developer-tools-network-tab)

Comment: Not same. I will update some request background.

Comment: @luckyzhou could you solve it?

Comment: @Zero not solved, this status was not the raw status in real client, looks like `canceled`,  `finished` and some non-code status will show `finished` in Har file.

Comment: I am having the same issue, wish there were answers to this...